# I need css animation on whole code and bullets after line break in the string. Also need control on time of loop

Tags: javascript, css

How can i apply bullets in this below mentioned code after line break. I mean when i break line, i need next line to start with the bullet. Also please apply css animation on this code. Also apply timing i-e when i run code, i can control after how many milliseconds the typing starts and when typing ends, i can control after how many milliseconds it starts again. Thanks

```js
var typeString = ['I\'m Mr. Frits  and I love Pakistan...:)'];

var i = 0;
var count = 0
var selectedText = '';
var text = '';
(function type() {
  if (count == typeString.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  selectedText = typeString[count];
  text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
  document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
  document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

  if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
    count++;
    i = 0;

  }
  setTimeout(type, 300);
}());

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="typing" class="typing"></pre>
```

Comment: What line breaks. You are planning to write more than one line and have bullets?

Comment: Line break can be done with `\n`. For instance - var typeString = ['I\'m Mr. Frits  \nand I love Pakistan...:)'];

Comment: yes i need more lines and have bullets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `\n` and the unicode `•`

```js
var typeString = ['• I\'m Mr. Frits\n• and I love Pakistan...:)'];

var i = 0;
var count = 0
var selectedText = '';
var text = '';
(function type() {
  if (count == typeString.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  selectedText = typeString[count];
  text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
  document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
  document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

  if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
    count++;
    i = 0;

  }
  setTimeout(type, 300);
}());

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="typing" class="typing"></pre>
```

Comment: Great. Working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use `&bull;` for the bullet character when generating the `text` variable

```
text = '&bull; '+ selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
```

Comment: No, he cannot use entities because they will be rendered like this`& b u l l ;`

Comment: just change this line ```text =  selectedText.slice(0, ++i);``` to ```text = '&bull; '+ selectedText.slice(0, ++i);``` @Shehryar